# Setting up multiple cores for apache solr for Ubuntu 12.04 and Drupal 7

Tags: 12.04, drupal, solr

I'm setting up solr locally for my development purposes and integration with Drupal 7. I'm not very familiar with tomcat. My background has primarily been LAMP setups.

So I went and installed the package provided by ubuntu for apache solr following this [guide](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way).

- `sudo apt-get install tomcat6 tomcat6-admin tomcat6-common tomcat6-user tomcat6-docs tomcat6-examples`
- `sudo apt-get install solr-tomcat`

I've got that working. The apt-get package manager does a great job and allows me to setup solr but with one core.

What steps need to be taken to enable multi core setup for apache solr?

And below is my `solr.xml` file:

**sudo nano /var/lib/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml**

```
<!--
    Context configuration file for the Solr Web App
-->

<Context path="/solr" docBase="/usr/share/solr"
   debug="0" privileged="true" allowLinking="true" crossContext="true">
  <!-- make symlinks work in Tomcat -->
  <Resources className="org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext" allowLinking="true" />

  <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/usr/share/solr" override="true" />
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide in OP is a quick start quide and does not touch on multi-core configuration.

There is an official guide in solr site: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin

It is very long. I will quote the initial setup portion.

### Partial Quote

**Configuration**

To enable support for dynamic SolrCore administration, place a file named solr.xml in the solr.home directory. Here is an example solr.xml file:

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
  <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
  <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
 </cores>
</solr>
```

You can also specify properties in solr.xml which can be used in the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml files.

```
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
 <property name="snapshooter" value="/home/solr-user/solr/bin/snapshooter.sh" />
 <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
  <core name="core0" instanceDir="core0">
    <property name="dataDir" value="/data/core0" />
  </core>
  <core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
 </cores>
</solr>
```

The properties can be container scope (i.e. specified after < solr > but outside of a < core > element) in which case it is automatically inherited by each core. Therefore, they can be used in any of the cores' configuration files.

The properties can also be defined in a core's scope (inside the < core > element) in which case they can be used only in that core's scope. If a property by that name already exists in the container scope then it will be overridden.

Besides them, a few properties are automatically added in the core scope. They are:

```
solr.core.name -- The core's name as defined in solr.xml

solr.core.instanceDir -- The core's instance directory (i.e. the directory under which that core's conf/ and data/ directory are located)

solr.core.dataDir -- The core's data directory (i.e. the directory under which that core's index directory are located)

solr.core.configName -- The name of the core's config file (solrconfig.xml by default)

solr.core.schemaName -- The name of the core's schema file (schema.xml by default)
```

Such properties can be used inside solrconfig.xml and schema.xml files by specifying an expression with optionally, a default value.

```
// Without a default value
${snapshooter}
// With a default value
${snapshooter:./solr/bin/snapshooter.sh}
```

The above expression will evaluate to the value specified in solr.xml for the property name "solr.snapshooter". If no value is defined in solr.xml, it will check if a system property by that name exists otherwise it will use the specified default value. If no default value is specified, a runtime exception will be thrown and the core may fail to startup.

Comment: Does this help?

Comment: While waiting for an answer, I got things working on my own, so I haven't followed your advice. However, I feel like I would be cheating you if you didn't get the bounty, so I assigned it. Thanks for taking the time.